# Python look-behind regex "fixed-width pattern" error while looking for consecutive repeated words

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text with words separated by `.`, with instances of 2 and 3 consecutive repeated words:

```
My.name.name.is.Inigo.Montoya.You.killed.my.father.father.father.Prepare.to.die-
```

I need to match them independently with regex, excluding the duplicates from the triplicates.

Since there are max. 3 consecutive repeated words, this

`r'\b(\w+)\.+\1\.+\1\b'`

successfully catches

```
father.father.father
```

However, in order to catch 2 consecutive repeated words, I need to make sure the next and previous words aren't the same. I can do a **negative look-ahead**

`r'\b(\w+)\.+\1(?!\.+\1)\b'`

but my attempts at the **negative look-behind**

`r'(?<!(\w)\.)\b\1\.+\1\b(?!\.\1)'`

either return a fixed-width issue (when I keep the `+`) or some other issue.

How should I correct the **negative look-behind**?

Comment: As you already said, you can't use lookbehinds if the match doesn't have a constant length.  You could use the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) library, which is an alternative regular expression library that allows variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Can the parts be separated with more than 1 dot? You used `\.+`, is it intended? See [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/v5ho7k), are you looking for something like this?

Comment: If it's just about identifying the duplicates from "multicates" [`\b(\w+)(?:\.(\1)(?:\.\1)+|\.(\1))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/d0L8yF/3/) Matches in group 3 are duplicates, matches in group 2 are tripli or more of the captured word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe regexes are not needed at all.

Using `itertools.groupby` does the job. It's *designed* to group equal occurrences of consecutive items.

- group by words (after splitting according to dots)
- convert to list and issue a `tuple` value,count only if length > 1

like this:

```
import itertools

s = "My.name.name.is.Inigo.Montoya.You.killed.my.father.father.father.Prepare.to.die"

matches = [(l[0],len(l)) for l in (list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(s.split("."))) if len(l)>1]
```

result:

```
[('name', 2), ('father', 3)]
```

So basically we can do whatever we want with this list of tuples (filtering it on the number of occurrences for instance)

Bonus (as I misread the question at first, so I'm leaving it in): to remove the duplicates from the sentence
- group by words (after splitting according to dots) like above
- take only key (value) of the values returned in a list comp (we don't need the values since we don't count)
- join back with dot

In one line (still using `itertools`):

```
new_s = ".".join([k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(s.split("."))])
```

result:

```
My.name.is.Inigo.Montoya.You.killed.my.father.Prepare.to.die
```

Comment: Can lose the `next`, I think, `k for k,_` should also work because the key _is_ each value.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need to delete the duplicates, just to identify them, but the tuple approach should work. I'll try it!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This turned out to be the simplest solution, so I've abandoned regex in this case. Thanks again!

Comment: you are a wise person. Complex regexes are sometimes very difficult to maintain / modify. In simple cases like that they're not really needed (well, when you're using python!)

Comment: Ah, the old 'regex is stupid when you have string split' argument.
`matches = [(l[0],len(l)) for l in (list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(s.split("."))) if len(l)>1]` is easier then `\b((\w+)\.+\2\.+\2?)\b`?! Regex is also cross plataform. Also, quick benchmark: 10000 loops, best of 3: 4.04 µs per loop  | 10000 loops, best of 3: 20.4 µs per loop - guess which one is using regex.

Comment: @joaoricardo000 _you_ are using "stupid", not me. Let me rephrase: regexes are very useful but sometimes difficult to create/maintain, that's also an important aspect. If performance matters, why not coding everything in assembly then? Also: regex is cross platform but syntaxes vary (sed != awk != python). Python is cross-platform. thanks for the benchmark, interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there might be an easier way to capture what you want without the negative look-behind:

```
r = re.compile(r'\b((\w+)\.+\2\.+\2?)\b')
r.findall(t)

> [('name.name.', 'name'), ('father.father.father', 'father')]
```

Just making the third repetition optional.

---

A version to capture any number of repetitions of the same word, can look something like this:

```
r = re.compile(r'\b((\w+)(\.+\2)\3*)\b')
r.findall(t)
> [('name.name', 'name', '.name'), ('father.father.father', 'father', '.father')]
```

Comment: For refusing of matching the trailing dot you can put the second dot withn a non-capturing group. `r'((\w+)\.+\2(?:\.+\2)?)'`.

Comment: Unless I've tried them wrong, these regex seem to match both the duplicates and the triplicates. I'm trying to find different regex to match duplicates and triplicates separately.